# how to put marquee div at the back of another none marquee div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make div with  inside marquee to put at the back of the div without marquee

I am having trouble in putting the marquee div at the back of the sphere div 
how can I do it using CSS ? I already put z-index :-9999; in a moving div but seems not working

here is my code

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container" >
        <div id="sphere" >
            <marquee>
            <div id="moving">

            </div>
            </marquee>
        </div>
    </div
</body>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000;

}
#sphere{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    opacity:0.6; // i reduce the opacity of the sphere so I can see the moving div at the back
    margin:auto;
    z-index:99999;
}
#moving{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-top:25px;
    z-index:-999999;
}
```

to make things clear below image shows what I want to do
[image]

basically I just want to put the moving div at the back of the sphere

Thanks in advance

Comment: It really looks simple but not sure why z-index not working could someone share their talents :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `#sphere`.

```
#sphere {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity:0.6;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:99999;
}
```

CSS: [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: You should also remove the `z-index`. It's not necessary. And it doesn't do anything; z-index only works for elements that have a `position` other than `static`.

Comment: Yes but I am curios if z-index in this problem can help? if we put position ?

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano Not in this particular case. Sure you can use z-index and positioning to position things in places where they normally wouldn't be; but in this particular case that could have worked if the _outside_ of the sphere was an element; if the sphere was a "hole" in this element and you would put the marquee behind it, so that it would have been visible through the hole. But that would have been a completely different structure.